# Access uploaded file on $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

Tags: php, web, upload, openshift

I uploaded some images to the folder `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploaded`, but I can't seem to retrieve those files using:

```
$_ENV['$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'].'uploaded/filename.jpg';
```

The error message was something like:

> The requested URL /var/lib/openshift/xxxxx/app-root/data/thumbnails/filename.jpg was not found on this server.

But when I ssh into my openshift app, **the file was there** in `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploaded/`

Is there a particular command to retrieve info from `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`?

*****edited*****

So I did some further research online and apparently the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` folder is not accessible. One way to work around is to create a symlink.
However another problem arises: I couldn't symlink `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploaded` and `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/src/img/uploaded`. The command I used was:

```
ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploaded ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}src/img/uploaded
```

But when I check it using `readlink` :

```
readlink -f ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}src/img/uploaded
```

it still displays the `${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}src/img/uploaded` folder instead of `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploaded`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Who owns the files and what are the permissions? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question. Now it's about creating symlink from $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/some/folder

Comment: Please double check if the $_ENV['$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] is really not working. It should.

Comment: Hi. So the solution was rather simple: set `.openshift/action_hooks/build` file to **'executable'**. A symlink to `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/src/img/uploaded` can then be specified in the build file, and the uploaded files can then be referred to by calling 
`$_ENV['$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'].'src/img/uploaded/filename.jpg';`

Comment: @joeleba please consider adding your solution as an answer to your own question, so that other stackoverflow users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was rather simple: set `.openshift/action_hooks/build` file to **'executable'**. A symlink to `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/src/img/uploaded` can then be specified in the build file, and the uploaded files can then be referred to by calling `$_ENV['$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'].'src/img/uploaded/filename.jpg';`